# Documenting setAs() and setOldClass() with Roxygen

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm developing a package that provides an S3 class named "Foo". It also provides an "as" method for coercing it to (someone else's) S4 class named "Bar". My code looks like this:

```
#' ...
setOldClass("Foo")

#' ...
setAs("Foo", "SpatialPointsDataFrame", function(from) { 
   # do stuff and return a SpatialPointsDataFrame
})
```

*edit* I've tried this:

```
#' ...
#' @name as
#' @export
setAs("Foo", "SpatialPointsDataFrame", function(from) { 
   # do stuff and return a SpatialPointsDataFrame
})
```

but then I get this from R CMD CHECK:

> checking whether the name space can be loaded with stated dependencies ... WARNING
>   Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : undefined exports: as
>   Calls: loadNamespace -> namespaceExport
>   Execution halted
>
> A namespace must be able to be loaded with just the base namespace loaded: otherwise if the  namespace gets loaded by a saved object, the session will be unable to start.
>
> Probably some imports need to be declared in the NAMESPACE file.

in a separate .R file, I have:

```
#' @importClassesFrom sp SpatialPointsDataFrame
```

I'm using hadley's devtools package, so I guess it's roxygen2. This is what I do:

```
R> document("MyPackage")
```

Comment: hadley's devtools package. edited to show best attempt.

Comment: Nice edit.  I'd be surprised if this doesn't get answered pretty soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roxygen2 parser didn't parse `setOldClass()` and `setAs()`.
We need to obtain appropriate `@name` tags.

```
#' "Foo" class
#'
#' @name Foo-class
#' @aliases Foo
#' @family Foo
#'
#' @exportClass Foo
setOldClass("Foo")

#' As("Foo", "SpatialPointsDataFrame")
#'
#' @name as
#' @family Foo
#'
#' @importClassesFrom sp SpatialPointsDataFrame
setAs("Foo", "SpatialPointsDataFrame", function(from) { 
   # do stuff and return a SpatialPointsDataFrame
})
```

I don't know about the `setAs()` function in detail, but the `as()` function is loaded from the methods package.
So, I think that we don't need `export(as)` entry in NAMESPACE.

Comment: Not really a roxygen pro, and this question is quite old, but... `setAs()` creates a method on `coerce`, with signature `coerce,Foo,SpatilPointsDataFrame`, so you'd like `@name coerce` and probably `@aliases coerce,Foo,SpatilPointsDataFrame-method`. You'd like to `@exportMethods coerce` to make this public.